# how to design like layout in android

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to design `like` layout. for example: when user touch like button then show a layout above it to show stickers.

please see this picture too understand my mean:

[image]

Can you guide me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have to keep a hidden linear layout above your layout for like button, and make it visible when like is clicked.

this hidden layout will contain your stickers:

example :

layout will look something like this:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/buttonContainer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/option1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/image1" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/option2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/image2" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/option3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/image3" />
</LinearLayout>
```

place it on top of layout for like button, customize it as per your need

and on click of your like button you have to make it visible like this;

```
findViewById(R.id.buttonContainer).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

and once an image is selected hide the view again like this:

```
 findViewById(R.id.buttonContainer).setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

hope this will help.

Comment: tnx, can you send me source code or example code  ? too see it and learn. tnx <3

Comment: i use this code, but when click on button show me FC error. my code :         bt = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button123);
        bt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
               l1 = view.findViewById(R.id.buttonContainer).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });

Comment: ohhhh. i make this. tnx for you help <3

Answer (score 3):

Rahul Tiwari has Nice Solution, Also you can have Relative Layout

inside Relative Layout You have Horizontal Linear Layout

And Finally set animation to Hide And Show Horizontal Linear Layout

Horizontal Linear Layout should be Forground of view

[read it](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/06/android-working-with-xml-animations/) to learn basic of animation

Answer (score 1):

I can guid you as following.

Create your layout as below.

And do visible when you want it on click like button.

And move it to the above of like button as following

lytMenu.setX(x, likeButton.getY() - lytMenu.getHeight());

If you do like this your menu layout will overlap other content as menu when you set visible it. Otherwise it will resize your mainLayout.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.sampleforstack.MainActivity" >

    <!--This is your main layout. Add your content here -->
    <LinearLayout 
        android:id="@+id/lytMain"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/accent_material_dark">

    </LinearLayout>
    <!--This is your menu layout. Add smile buttons here -->
    <LinerLayout
        android:id="@+id/lytMenu"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="gone">
    </LinerLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```